# How can I trace Win32 calls on Windows Mobile or system calls on Android?

Tags: android, windows-mobile, maemo

For Windows(All versions) we can use - [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), [StraceNT](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm)

Linux has a host of tracing utilities - [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace)

How do I do a similar thing on Mobiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://benno.id.au/android/strace

taken from [here](http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/18/android-runtime-strace)

Comment: I know Maemo provides bash shell with root access. Can I use strace on that? Can someone with experience on Maemo confirm this?